# Oracle WebLogic Admin server does not come up after upgrading from 10.3.6 to 12.1.3

Tags: java, hibernate, weblogic12c

Steps followed:

Installed WebLogic 12.1.3 and JAVA 1.8

1. Removed customization in config.xml and SetDomainEnv.sh in my current 10.3.6 mydomain.
   10.3.6 mydomain JAVA version:jdk1.6.0_45/ 
   Current JAVA version used 1.8
2. Used WLST on 12.1.3

   ```
   readDomainForUpgrade('/usr/prod/domains/<mydomain>')
   updateDomain()
   closeDomain()
   ```
3. Tried to start Admin server on the upgraded mydomain.
4. Tried several other options and methods of upgrading and I land up in the same place in the ADMin.log

> ```
> <Jan 7, 2016 9:41:42 AM PST> <Info> <org.hibernate.validator.util.Version> <prdrsps101> <My_Admin> <[STANDBY]   ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1452188502600> <BEA-000000> <Hibernate Validator 12.1.3.0.0> 
> <Jan 7, 2016 9:41:42 AM PST> <Info> <org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver> <prdrsps101> <My_Admin> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1452188502606> <BEA-000000> <Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver
> ```

What can I do to fix it problem?

Comment: what is your previous java version for(Weblogic 10.3.6) ??

Comment: My previous version of JAVA was jdk1.6.0_45/

Answer (score 0):

weblogic 12.1.3 uses jdk 1.7 or higher. so install first jdk 1.7 verify the version by running the command "`java -version`". you can follow the link
https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1213/gg-monitor/GMINS/prepare.htm#GMINS128

Comment: Weblogic 12.1.3 is certified for JAVA 1.8 - This is confirmed by Oracle team. We also need support for SHA2 algorithm, so JAVA 1.7 will not work for us.I also know that JAVA 1.7 update 85 will support SHA2 but that is not the path we want to go towards.  We are using weblogic 12.1.3 and JAVA 1.8 right now. The error seen is in JAVA 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Could bring up Admin server -> issue was that config.xml had to be edited to remove references to other boxes in the domain.With just one managed instance in config.xml, Admin server came up.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was an issue with one of the node machine in the cluster. I had to restart that particular physical machine and then start the AdminServer process to boot up successfully.